# Finding coefficient in expression

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have expressions like these:

```
expr1 = -2 a Z[-2] - 2 b Z[-1] - 2 Z[-1] + a Z[-1]
expr2 = -2 a Z[-2] - 2 b Z[-1] - 2 Z[-1] + a Z[-1] + c Z[0]
expr3 = -2 a Z[-2] - 2 c Z[-1] - 2 Z[-1] + a Z[-1] + c Z[0]
```

and I want to find out whether an expression contains as coefficient `a`, `b` and `c`. So what I want is a function `f[expr]`, such that

```
f[expr1] (* false because it only contains a and b *)
f[expr2] (* true because it contains a, b and c *)
f[expr3] (* false because it only contains a and c *)
```

The only way I can think of is converting it to a string and do a string-search, but I'm sure there must be a more clever way. I was trying to use `Case[]`, but I was not able to find a solution yet.

---

**Edit:**
There are several different solutions, I tested them on speed. Run each of the functions 100.000 times (with one argument only, in case the `{a,b,c}`-list was a function-argument, it was replaced to be constant - for fair comparison) with the `expr1`, `expr2`, `expr3` expressions.

*Results:*

- Dr. belisarius: 11.3443515 sec
- Bill: 2.0469818 sec
- eldo's 1st: 3.6095660 sec
- eldo's 2nd: 2.4532568 sec
- Suba Thomas: 6.8753645 sec
- (Algohi: My Mathmatica9 does not support `SubsetQ` unfortunatly.)

The fastest solution will get the acceptance-reward, after roughly 24hours of the original questions. Thanks for the infos and the fun :-)

Comment: Offhand, you might look at `CoefficientList` (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html) or this tutorial at extracting pieces of algebraic expressions (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PickingOutPiecesOfAlgebraicExpressions.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
check[expr_, vars_]:= Not[Or @@ Map[FreeQ[expr, #] &, vars]];
check[expr1, {a, b, c}]
check[expr2, {a, b, c}]
check[expr3, {a, b, c}]
```

(* False, True, False *)

Answer (score 4):

```
f[expr_] := Count[D[expr, {{a, b, c}}], 0] == 0
f /@ {expr1, expr2, expr3}
```

> {False, True, False}

Comment: wow that is an unusual solution :)

Comment: Turns out to also have the fewest characters (so far). But not the fastest!

Answer (score 3):

```
f[x_] := Not[Or @@ (PossibleZeroQ /@ Last@CoefficientArrays[x, {a, b, c}])]
f /@ {expr1, expr2, expr3}
(* {False, True, False} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Table[Union@Flatten@Map[Cases[ex, #, Infinity] &, {a, b, c}] == 
 {a, b, c}, {ex, {expr1, expr2, expr3}}]
```

> {False, True, False}

Or

```
f[ex_] := 
 Union@Flatten@Map[Cases[ex, #, Infinity] &, {a, b, c}] == {a, b, c}

f /@ {expr1, expr2, expr3}
```

> {False, True, False}

Or

```
 f[ex_] := And @@ Map[MemberQ[ex, #, Infinity] &, {a, b, c}]

 f /@ {expr1, expr2, expr3}
```

> {False, True, False}

Answer (score 2):

```
f[expr_, var_List] := SubsetQ[Level[expr, {-1}], var]
```